# Cannot close code review response work items in Visual Studio or DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, version-control, tfvc, workitem, team-explorer

I'm trying to close a code review response work item in Devops/Visual studio and I get the Field 'Closed Status' cannot be empty error and I am unable to close the work item. The Closed Status is not editable in Visual Studio or DevOps.

[image: Visual Studio]

[image: DevOps]

I don't want to be editing the "Closed Status" in excel, I need a easier way of handling this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the same, after investigation, it's a known issue which reported [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/code-review-response-error-field-closed-status-can/107593).

You can use the workaround below to close them:

1. Open the code review requests in a DevOps query.
2. Select the request, on the `right` side pane, change the state to `closed`, it will report the error. **Ignore that error** and continue to step3.
   [image]
3. click `...` on the left pane after the ticket name, click `edit`:
   [image]
4. In the popup select "Close Status Code" and pick value 5 and press OK. This will update the Closed Status (which was the cause for the error that we saw in step 2).
   [image]
5. Now just press Save and the ticket will be closed.
   [image]